# ¿Por qué al usar NavLink pierdo los estilos?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo un `Button Group`, pero cuando ya quiero agregar una redireccion (hacer útil el botón), se cambian todos los estilos, por unos default, o no se de donde salen.
[image: IMAGEN CON LA VISTA PREVIA DE LO QUE PASA]

En rojo el que tiene los el NavLink, el resto está default. Así tengo mi componente:

```
export default function BasicButtonGroup() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
        <NavLink to="/one/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Button>One</Button>
        </NavLink>
        <Button>Two</Button>
        <Button>Three</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anidar un boton dentro de un link no es valido. Utiliza `as`.

```
export default function BasicButtonGroup() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
        <Button as={NavLink} to="/one/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>One</Button>
        <Button>Two</Button>
        <Button>Three</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```